# Grouping of all possible combinations of points taken m at a time into r groups

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

I want to group all possible combinations of points taken **m** at a time into **r** groups.

> Points = [A,B,C,D........] Total **n** points

Combinations of these points taken **m** at a time will be a list **l**

```
l = list(itertools.combinations(points,m))
```

How can I further group it into r groups such that **i-th** element of each group has no similar points.

For example,

> Points = [A,B,C,D] m = 2 and r = 2
>
> l = [[A,B],[A,C],[A,D],[B,C],[B,D],[C,D]]

So groups will be

> Group 1 = [[A,B],[A,C],[A,D]] and corresponding to it Group 2 =
>   [[C,D],[B,D],[B,C]]

Note : The points in the **i-th** index of group 1 and group 2 have no similar points.

I want to do it for **n** number of points taken **m** at a time and grouping it into r groups.

Please provide me the algorithm.

Also note that when  the number of points increases, the possible combinations also increase if we want more than 2 groups.

Comment: Is this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html ?

Comment: Yes it is somewhat same. It will help me in solving my problem. Can you provide me the solution for the Social Golfer Problem ? I need the algorithm or code in python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to implement the logic in pseudocode? -please post.

Comment: David's link clearly says the problem is unsolved in general. You will have to do some research to see what has been found.

Comment: You say it is somewhat the same, but I can't see any differences. Are there any? What are the constraints for `r`, `m`, and `n`? If they're too large this might be hopeless. Also, clearly `r × m ≤ n`, can it be that `r × m < n`?

Comment: We need to store all the possible combinations of r x m in n groups.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem! I've implemented a naive brute force solution. This is probably too slow but it's a starting point.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

points = 'ABCDEF'
r = 3
m = len(points) // r
all_combinations = list(combinations(points, m))
group_length = len(all_combinations) // r
assert r * group_length == len(all_combinations)
found = set()

for combinations_permutation in permutations(all_combinations):
    groups = [combinations_permutation[group_length * i: group_length * (i + 1)]
              for i in range(r)]
    transpose = zip(*groups)

    # Avoid very similar-looking solutions
    canonical = frozenset(map(frozenset, transpose))

    if (canonical not in found and
            all(len(col) == len(set(col))
                for col in (sum(column, ()) for column in transpose))):
        found.add(canonical)
        for group in groups:
            print ', '.join(map(''.join, group))
        print '----'
```

Here's the start of the output:

```
AB, AC, AD, AE, AF
CD, BE, BF, BD, BC
EF, DF, CE, CF, DE
----
AB, AC, AD, AE, AF
CD, BF, BE, BC, BD
EF, DE, CF, DF, CE
----
AB, AC, AD, AE, AF
CE, BD, BE, BF, BC
DF, EF, CF, CD, DE
----
AB, AC, AD, AE, AF
CE, BF, BC, BD, BE
DF, DE, EF, CF, CD
```